# Ionic : troubles putting an ionic slider in a list

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, slider

So in a form I have a list in which I would like to put a slider. I kinda achieved it thanks to this [codepen](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/AjgEB), BUT there is some issues I am not able to solve.

[image: screenshot of the app]

As you can see the slider is at the right place (and it works!) but the dots that should be at the bottom of the icons are misplaced. At first I though it would be a css problem and remove my style.css **but it did not solve the problem**.

Here is my piece of code for the slider in the html :

```
        <div class="item">
            PICK SOME FOOD
            <ion-slide-box>
                <ion-slide>
                    <div class="box">
                        <img class="logo" src="img/pie.png">
                    </div>
                </ion-slide>
                <ion-slide>
                    <div class="box">
                        <img class="logo" src="img/ice_cream.png">
                    </div>
                </ion-slide>
                <ion-slide>
                    <div class="box">
                        <img class="logo" src="img/cheese.png">
                    </div>
                </ion-slide>
                <ion-slide>
                    <div class="box">
                        <img class="logo" src="img/steak.png">
                    </div>
                </ion-slide>
                <ion-slide>
                    <div class="box">
                        <img class="logo" src="img/apple.png">
                    </div>
                </ion-slide>
                <ion-slide>
                    <div class="box">
                        <img class="logo" src="img/pasta.png">
                    </div>
                </ion-slide>
            </ion-slide-box>
        </div>
```

And here is what I have in my controller :

```
    // Food slider

    scope.nextSlide = function () {
        $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.next();
    }
```

That's quite simple .. Any ideas :) ?

Comment: Which version of Ionic are you using? ion-slide-box deprecated from latest versions of Ionic.

Comment: The 1.7.16 one @HarishKommuri